# How can I stop Xamarin from building my app with bitcode enabled?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, bitcode

In the configurations from my iOS build, there is no option to disable bitcode. While in Xcode it is possible to set ENABLE_BITCODE=NO

I need this because my linked frameworks are not build with bitcode, and nowadays Apple does not allow half-bitcode-compiled apps anymore.

Comment: I am kinda sitting in the same boat, just reversed. My library does include Bitcode while my main project does not. I tried setting the property MtouchEnableBitcoe to "true" but "Bitcode is currently not supported on iOS" as the error message promptly told me. Really hope we can find a solution for this asap.

Comment: Bitcode is supported in Xamarin. Maybe post your error/issue on stackoverflow and send me the link ;)

Comment: My thread is actually right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689054/sudden-error-when-uploading-to-itunesconnect-itms-90635-invalid-mach-o-format

When I set the MtouchEnableBitcode property to true Xamarin Studio literally tells me "Error executing task Mtouch: Bitcode is currently not supported on iOS"

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `.csproj` for your iOS application, search for the `PropertyGroup` for the release configuration that you need to turn off bit code for, i.e.:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|iPhone' ">
```

Within that group, see if a `MtouchEnableBitcode` already exists and edit it, otherwise add:

```
<MtouchEnableBitcode>false</MtouchEnableBitcode>
```

Comment: For some reason my app is still not valid says Apple:

'ERROR ITMS-90668: "Invalid Bundle Executable. The executable file SoToGo.Touch.app/Frameworks/FrameWorkName.framework/FrameWorkName contains incomplete bitcode. To compile binaries with complete bitcode, open Xcode and choose Archive in the Product menu."'

How can i disable bitcode for a native reference (Framework) ?

Comment: @Jelle If you `otool` your framework's library, what is the address and size of the llvm segment? something like: `otool -arch arm64 FrameWorkName.framework/FrameWorkName  | grep __bitcode -A 3`

Comment: I'm missing an argument for the otool: one of -fahlLtdoOrTMRIHCGScisP or --version must be specified

Comment: @Jelle I missed the `-l` so try `otool -arch arm64 -l FrameWorkName.framework/FrameWorkName | grep __bitcode -A 3`

Comment: Then nothing comes out. Nothing found I guess. When I run the command without grep, there is a whole list of things. (btw: thanks for the help so far)

Comment: I saw some other post about this, they suggested grep __LLVM then I get this result: `Load command 2
      cmd LC_SEGMENT_64
  cmdsize 152
  segname __LLVM
   vmaddr 0x000000000000c000
   vmsize 0x0000000000004000
  fileoff 49152
 filesize 16384
  maxprot 0x00000003
 initprot 0x00000003
   nsects 1
    flags 0x4
Section
  sectname __bundle
   segname __LLVM
      addr 0x000000000000c000
      size 0x0000000000000001
    offset 49152
     align 2^0 (1)
    reloff 0
    nreloc 0
     flags 0x00000000
 reserved1 0
 reserved2 0` But I think there is no bitcode in this frmwrk

Comment: @Jelle `addr 0x000000000000c000 size 0x0000000000000001` yes, with a size of one there is no llvm bitcode in that library. Seems like Apple made a change recently and multiple people are getting this ITMS-90668 error...

Comment: They did indeed. Still strange they thing it's a incomplete bitcode build, while I disabled bitcode for the whole project.

Comment: For the record, I was also using a Binding Lib to a Native Framework in this project, which had bitcode enabled...

Answer (score 1):

I am able to build the application with bitcode disabled by adding following lines to the iOS app project's .csproj file immediately before the closing `</Project>` tag.

```
<Target Name="BeforeCodesign">
  <Exec Command="$(_SdkDevPath)\Toolchains\XcodeDefault.xctoolchain\usr\bin\bitcode_strip %(_Frameworks.FullPath) -r -o %(_Frameworks.FullPath)" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

My team and I have done what Vittal Pai and SushiHangover suggested but we faced another error:

> Command
>   "\Applications\Xcode.app\Contents\Developer\Toolchains\XcodeDefault.xctoolchain\usr/bin\bitcode_strip
>   PathToOurFrameWorks -r -o PathToOurFrameWorks" ended with code 3

^ It's translated from French so please don't bite me too hard :)

The only way we made it work was by importing the project from our GitHub to a Mac with VS 2017 and then rebuilding it there.

The error is still present on the Windows version but it's gone on the Mac version.

Comment: Maybe updating to the latest Xamarin.VS on your Windows Machine ?